# how to download php53 on centos 5.3 ( i had installed php54 before)

Tags: linux, centos5, php53

I would like to install php53 on centos5.3 (had installed php54 before but removed) I did it as below.

1. sudo yum remove php php-common php-cli
2. sudo yum install php53
3. sudo yum install zabbix-web-mysql

but when i tried last thing, it shows the following error:

```
Installed: php53.x86_64 0:5.3.3-26.el5_11
Dependency Installed: php53-cli.x86_64 0:5.3.3-26.el5_11 php53-common.x86_64 0:5.3.3-26.el5_11
Complete!
[root@QCacti ~]# sudo yum install zabbix-web-mysql
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * epel: ftp.jaist.ac.jp
 * atomic: mirrors.neusoft.edu.cn
 * rpmforge: ftp.riken.jp
 * base: centos.mirror.cdnetworks.com
 * updates: centos.mirror.cdnetworks.com
 * extras: centos.mirror.cdnetworks.com
 * addons: centos.mirror.cdnetworks.com
Excluding Packages from CentOS / Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5 - atomicrocketturtle.com
Finished
Setting up Install Process
Parsing package install arguments
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package zabbix-web-mysql.x86_64 0:2.4.7-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: zabbix-web = 2.4.7-1.el5 for package: zabbix-web-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: php-mysql for package: zabbix-web-mysql
--> Running transaction check
---> Package zabbix-web.x86_64 0:2.4.7-1.el5 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php53-bcmath for package: zabbix-web
--> Processing Dependency: php53-gd for package: zabbix-web
--> Processing Dependency: php53-mbstring for package: zabbix-web
--> Processing Dependency: php53-xml for package: zabbix-web
---> Package php-mysql.x86_64 0:5.1.6-45.el5_11 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: php-common = 5.1.6-45.el5_11 for package: php-mysql
--> Processing Dependency: php-pdo for package: php-mysql
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php53-xml.x86_64 0:5.3.3-26.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package php-common.x86_64 0:5.1.6-45.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package php-pdo.x86_64 0:5.1.6-45.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package php53-gd.x86_64 0:5.3.3-26.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package php53-bcmath.x86_64 0:5.3.3-26.el5_11 set to be updated
---> Package php53-mbstring.x86_64 0:5.3.3-26.el5_11 set to be updated
--> Processing Conflict: php53-common conflicts php-common
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
php53-common-5.3.3-26.el5_11.x86_64 from installed has depsolving problems
  --> php53-common conflicts with php-common
Error: php53-common conflicts with php-common
```

Comment: Please use [Markdown](http://serverfault.com/editing-help) and/or the formatting options in the edit menu to properly type-set your posts to improve their readability. Also use cut-and-paste for posting console output and format it as "`code`" rather than posting screenshots. That improves readability, attracts better answers  and allows indexing by search engines, which may help people with similar questions.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you're installing PHP 5.3, not just PHP?

Try following [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/centos-5.6-php53-common-conflicts-with-php-common) and specify php version during installation like:

`yum install php53 php53-cli php53-common php53-gd php53-imap php53-intl php53-mbstring php53-mysql php53-odbc php53-pdo php53-pspell php53-snmp php53-xml php53-xmlrpc`

Also, before downgrading, you should remove php54, you sad you had been using:

```
rpm -qa | grep -i php
yum remove php
yum remove php-cli
yum remove php-pdo
yum remove php-common
yum remove <other php packages>
```

Now the `zabbix-web-mysql` you're trying to install has dependency on php5.4. It is not supported with PHP 5.3, however you can try to install it from RPM-package without dependencies:

```
wget http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/2.4/rhel/5/x86_64/zabbix-web-mysql-2.4.7-1.el5.x86_64.rpm
wget http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/2.4/rhel/5/x86_64/zabbix-web-2.4.7-1.el5.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh --nodeps zabbix-web-2.4.7-1.el5.x86_64.rpm zabbix-web-mysql-2.4.7-1.el5.x86_64.rpm`
```

But me why would you use `CentOS 5.3` which should have been upgraded to `5.11` like 5 years ago?

[You should consider installing zabbix on CentOS 7 instead](https://www.zabbix.org/wiki/InstallOnCentOS_RHEL)

Comment: thank you for your help. cause i am using that server for test, i made it like what you said at first. Thank you so much haha

Comment: well, you should consider upgrading, otherwise you might run into dependency-hell when trying to install anything (probably you're going there right now with zabbix)

Comment: @PYO So has you solved the problem? It's unclear from your message...